# How convert data type from string (exponential note) to float?

Tags: python, pandas

I can not convert cell from string to float. I tried to make dtype='float', when i import from file, but I cannot bypass that first 2 columns are date and time. So i want to change format of selected columns later on.

I look in this forum for some cool tips, but none of them works for me.
I tried several methods.

`df=cD1.apply(pd.to_numeric)`

I tried to use locale.atof() in some cell

```
a=cD1.iloc[1242,2]
print(type(a))
a=locale.atof(a)
```

I try even make it with numpy (cD2 is one column)

```
a=np.array(cD2)
a.astype(float)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.array(a))
```

I expect to have float numbers, but I keep getting the same error

```
ValueError: ('Unable to parse string "7,2785E+2" at position 0', 'occurred at index U1rms')
```

**EDIT**

```
pf=pd.read_csv('P07_proces.txt',sep="\t")
cD1=pf.iloc[:,[2,3,4]]
cD2=pf.iloc[:,3]
```

in my 0 column is date and in 1st column is time

And now i try your idea, but it's not working.

```
cD2['I1rms']=cD2['I1rms'].astype(float)
```

Comment: with `read_csv` you can pass `dtype`, which can be a dictionary, for example, it can be `{'cD2': float}`. Aslo, `DataFrame` and `Series` have `astype` method as well, i.e. `df['cD2'] = df['cD2'].astype(float)`.

Comment: I edit my post with some info, but i cannot make it work.

Comment: try `float("7,2785E+2")` and you will see it is not float number. It needs dot instead comma `float("7.2785E+2")`. So you would have to change dot to comma before you try to convert to float

Comment: The problem might be `7,2785E+2` uses comma separated while pandas uses point separated, i.e. `"7.2785E+2"`. Fix that in your data, and it would be automatic.

Comment: Look at usings `thousands` parameter in pd.read_csv to handle ',', comma.

Comment: Thank you for your help, all i did is 
    cD1.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',','.'))
    cD1 = cD1.stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()
    cD2=cD2.astype(float)